# STM32CubeIDE - expected specifier-qualifier-list before __packed

Tags: iar, stm32cubeide

I'm porting code written in IAR to STCube.

The same code that works in IAR has the error below on the STCube:

Error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before __packed

```
typedef union
{
    __packed struct
   {
      uint8_t Effect;
      uint16_t Index;
      uint8_t Xini;
      uint8_t YIni;
      uint8_t XFim;
      uint8_t YFim;
      uint8_t NextEffect;
    };
    uint8_t data[8];
 } FILE_UNION;
 extern FILE_UNION FILE_TIME;
```

Does anyone know which parameter is missing in the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Solution.

```
 __attribute__ ((packed)) struct;
```